# showing a full screen div when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, hide, overlay, show

I would like to know if someone knows a way to show a DIV over my page when clicking on a link, using Javascrpit I guess...

for example on this page when clicking on "Kent Fonn Skåre" on the left.
http://kentskare.com/

I have a website and I would like to make a page with biography, contacts, etc... that will appears over my website (not in a popup exactly like on the example above) when clicking on a link called "information" for example... and when clicking on "close" then going back to the main website.

can you help me with this ? or give me keywords to search tutorials ?

thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called 'Modal dialog.' One such tool is by jQuery UI, 
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you want is a modal. Here are two examples of a modal that you can get for free:

- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
- http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

If you don't like them; just search google for "javascript modal".